# Echo HTML content in specific line of another HTML file with PHP

Tags: php

Good Afternoon!

I have a login script in HTML, PHP and MySQL and it's working fine, but I want the Login page to print an error message with a simple 'p' when fields are empty.

My login.php page:

```
<form action="includes/loginprocess.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
 <input type="password"name="pass" placeholder="Password">
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

loginprocess.php:

```
<?php

// Includes the database connection file.
include("mysqlconnection.php");

// Check if there was a POST or if some field are empty.
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['user']) OR empty($_POST['pass']))) {
header("Location: ../login.php"); exit;
}

//And a lot of other things come after...
```

All I want to know is if there's any way to make loginprocess.php echo some simple message above the inputs in login.php like:

```
<form action="loginprocess.php" method="POST">

 //This!!!
 <p style="color:red;">Fields Empty!</p> 

 <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
 <input type="password"name="pass" placeholder="Password">
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

That will help me a lot, thanks guys.

Comment: you can do this using html5 form validation method or javascript

Comment: too many ways to do this and how you want it to appear. As in "immediately when clicking", or as in "after" they clicked?

Comment: After submit is clicked I want **loginprocess.php** to add a `<p>Forms Empty!</p>` inside **login.php** without html validators.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the validation to catch whether inputs are empty, then you should simply mark the inputs as required and let the html5 validators take care of it for you.

```
<form action="includes/loginprocess.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required>
 <input type="password"name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jeff, it helped me very much. But what I really want is that after submit is clicked, **loginprocess.php** add a `<p>Forms Empty!</p>`, (or if the password is incorrect) inside **login.php** without html validators. Anyway, I want to print anything its needed inside a script from another script. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna search how.

Comment: you might also consider using jQuery's library for [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)